# Does voltage drop resistor affect power dissipation?

Tags: ldo, heatsink, power-dissipation

I need to power an RFID from 24 V DC voltage. The RFID requires max. 9 V and max. 120 mA. The RFID suggests a 7809 linear voltage regulator. I thought too much and I want to use a 7809 because if I use a switching regulator (10$) for 24 V to 12 V and then 12 V to 9 V with 7809, it costs a lot.

If I go with 24 V to 9 V, (24 V - 9 V) * 120 mA = 1.8W,

If I go with 24 V to 12 V and then 12 V to 9 V ,(12 V - 9 V) * 120 mA = 0.36 W.

It will take ~22000 hrs of operation to realize the $8 savings from going to the switching regulator vs going for the linear regulator and that's okay for me.

[image]

- I made this circuit; someone suggested to me to use a 82 Ω, 2 W resistor. If I use that resistor, would I still need to use a heat sink? If I add that resistor (82 Ω), is power dissipation = (10.2 V - 9 V) * 120 mA = 0.24 W ? (I used a 75 Ω resistor for the RFID part)
- I read somewhere (I couldn't find the link) that says you need to put in 3 different output capacitors for clear power, is that correct? Are these capacitors okay? And all these capacitors are ceramic, should I use electrolytic ones?
- I found this heatsink [özdisan.comdatasheet](https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/537658_3966414.pdf), this heatsink has only graphic and it says that at 2 W the rise in temperature will be 20°C, 5°C from junction to case, plus another 5°C for the TO220 case to heatsink, resulting in 30°C isn't it wonderful?

I have another heat sink [farnell.com](https://uk.farnell.com/aavid-thermalloy/6098bg/heat-sink-to-220-202-14-c-w/dp/1213463?st=to-220%20heatsink), it doesn't have a graphic but it says Thermal Resistance is 14°C/W , how can I compare which is better? I couldn't get its Thermal Resistance: 14°C/W . Thank you.

Comment: The reg will still drop around 5V, so thats around 1W. The TO220 pkg is around 66degreeC/W, so you need a heatsink. Your first heatsink is 10C/W so better than the Farnell at 14C/W.

Comment: thank you Kartman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a bunch of switchers on [Farnell](https://fr.farnell.com/w/c/protection-d-alimentation-de-lignes/alimentations/convertisseurs-dc-dc/convertisseurs-regulateur-lineaire-remplacement-broche-a-broche-dc-dc/prl/resultats?tension-de-sortie-nom-=9v&sort=P_PRICE), starting at 1.69€ plus tax.

It's cheaper than a 7809 plus heat sink.

> someone suggested to me to use a 82 Ω, 2 W resistor. If I use that resistor, would I still need to use a heat sink?

Plot the regulator dissipation (24-9-i*R)*i with i from 0 to your max current and check. With the resistor, the regulator maximum dissipation will not be a t maximum current but a bit below.

If the load draws 120mA maximum during pulses, but has much lower average current, then perhaps you can get away with a smaller heat sink.

If load current is constant, then make sure to use a 3W resistor if you intend it to dissipate 2W, and solder it with long legs. Otherwise it'll barbecue your board.

Also 7809 needs more than 1.2V drop.

> this heatsink has only graphic and it says that at 2 W the rise in temperature will be 20°C, 5°C from junction to case, plus another 5°C for the TO220 case to heatsink, resulting in 30°C isn't it wonderful?

20°C/2W = 10°C/W, That's good.

> I have another heat sink farnell.com, it doesn't have a graphic but it says Thermal Resistance is 14°C/W , how can I compare which is better? I couldn't get its Thermal Resistance: 14°C/W . Thank you.

Thermal resistance seems worse, you need a powerful soldering iron to solder it because of the thick feet, and it's heavier.

Comment: you helped me a lot. I need to use LDO for RFID. They suggest me 7809. You answered before my question. I don't want to use switching regulator for 24V to 12V. It is expensive and complicated. Probably that 120 mA is not constant so I won't use that 82 ohm resistor. I will use directly 24V to 9V with 20°C/2W = 10°C/W this heat sink. I calculated   20°C+  5°C + 5°C =30 °C rise. If the ambient goes up even 60°C , It will still work with out problem with 90°C. Am I thinking right? I updated schematic in the question section.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome You don't need an LDO (low-dropout regulator); you have 15V of headroom, there's nothing low-dropout about that. That's good, because the 7809 is _not_ an LDO; it's a regular linear regulator with a fairly large voltage drop (probably about 2.5V). Also, bobflux showed you a switching regulator that is not expensive and not complicated.

Comment: @marcelm thank you for your comment. Here is my RFID [aliexpress](https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/4000601988338.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.259f72a7hw7sRC&algo_pvid=6d9fdbf6-d346-41fe-ab8c-6911bd6c4794&algo_exp_id=6d9fdbf6-d346-41fe-ab8c-6911bd6c4794-16) bottom side, there is a schematic for power. They suggest 7809.

Comment: Yes heat sink will be fine.

Comment: Thank you bobflux. Have a nice day.